# How to Pre-select [checked] first radio button using ngfor loop index value

Tags: javascript, angular

I have to pre-select  initial radio button in a group

in this below ng-for loop method using index-based condition on input

```
<div class="left-menu" *ngFor="let position of allStyles">
        <h4>{{position.position_name}}</h4>
        <div class="checkbox" *ngFor="let subpostion of position.sub_position.items; index as i" >
            <label>
               <input type="radio" [id]="position.position_name+i" [name]="'group'+position.position_name" [value]="subpostion.id" [(ngModel)]="custom[position.position_name]"  [checked]="i === 0" >
                      {{subpostion.subposition_name}}
            </label>
         </div>
</div>
```

**Issue:**

First radio button in a group not selecting based on condition i given [checked]="i === 0"

**Note:**

1.Want to control the pre-select from view part itself not to set any defaults in the component.ts

2.Please don't mark it as a duplicate I referred all links as related to it no solution

Comment: Have you tried ng-checked="$first"

Comment: yes i tried 
[https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xtc52g?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html]  
stackblitz link

[https://angular.io/api/common/NgForOf] angular 5

Answer (score 2):

If you are working with `value` and `[(ngModel)]` then you must be initialize the the value which radio button you want to select first to maintain it's value and No need to set `checked` property in html template.

example here :[value and ngModel](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zwwoks)

Comment: yes it affects when I remove [(ngModel)] but value need inside my component
(two-way binding)

Comment: i am updating my post. you can check now.

Comment: yes but m looking for a solution from HTML template itself, 
because button group will get change from controller dynamically based on parent radio selection. 
so not to specify any initials which I don't know exactly.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example:

```
<tr *ngFor="let entry of entries; let idx = index">
        <td>{{ entry.description }}</td>
        <td><input type="radio" name="radiogroup" (change)="onSelectionChange(entry)" [checked]="(idx === 0)" [value]="entry.id"></td>
</tr>
```